# compare current cell and previous cell in excel style without loop

Tags: r

I want to create a indicator variable after comparing the current value of a variable and the previous value. The logic is like this:`if current value= previous value, then indicator =1,else 0`. The first indicator value is truncated because there is no comparison.
It needs to be fast because I have lots of groups to compare in my data( I did not include the group for simplicity)

```
> dt<-c('a','a','a','b','a','a','c','c') 
>  indicator
 [1] NA  1  1  0  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R you can remove the last elements and the first element of the vector with `head()` and `tail()` and do the comparison, then add the NA to the front.

```
c(NA, as.numeric(head(dt, -1) == tail(dt, -1)))
```

If `dt` were a vector of numbers, you could use `diff` like

```
dn <- c(1,1,1,2,1,1,3,3)
c(NA, (diff(dn)==0)+0)
```

(using `+0` rather than `as.numeric` to make the booleans 1's and 0's.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Lag` from `Hmisc` package

Ignoring the first value with [-1] and adding `NA` at the beginning.

```
library(Hmisc)
c(NA, as.numeric(dt== Lag(dt))[-1])

#[1] NA  1  1  0  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `rle` in base R:

```
v <- rle(dt)[[1]]
x <- rep(1:length(v),v)
indicator <- c(NA, (diff(x)==0)*1)

#[1] NA  1  1  0  0  1  0  1
```

- `v`: gets the number of times each character is repeated
- `x`: contains the respective numeric vector from `dt` to benefit from `diff`